# How to use extensions and IBInspectable to set label text colours for 2 theme modes?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

I have a switch button to change the theme of the app to dark mode and day mode. I am using an extension to change the color of all labels in the app according to the selected colors in attribute inspector with the help of IBInspectable because my project is finished and I have to implement theme in this large project.

So I have created an example project to explain what my problem is. What am I missing?

```
import UIKit
//singleton variable to bool var to check theme status
class Theme {
    static let shared = Theme()
    var isDarkMode = true
}

//Extension made by me for the labels to select the text colors for
//both in dak and day mode separately

extension UILabel {
    @IBInspectable var DayModeColor : UIColor {
        set{
            self.textColor = newValue
        }
        get{
            return textColor
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var DarkModeColor : UIColor {
        set{
            self.textColor = newValue
        }
        get{
            return textColor
        }
    }
    
    open override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        if Theme.shared.isDarkMode == true {
            self.textColor = DarkModeColor
        }
        else {
            self.textColor = DayModeColor
        }
    }
}

//View Load

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var lblStatus: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    //Switc Button Action
    @IBAction func themeSwitchAction(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn == true {
            Theme.shared.isDarkMode = true
            lblStatus.text = "Dark Mode"
        }
        else {
            Theme.shared.isDarkMode = false
            lblStatus.text = "Day Mode"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have selected White color for Dark mode and Black color for Day mode

Comment: but nothing happens or change

Answer (score 1):

You have added your login in `awakeFromNib()` which will be called once.

You have to get the value of light and dark colour every time you change switch position, which can be achieved by getting the values stored in respective properties and setting it to the label.

I have made some changes to your code and pasted it here:

```
@IBAction func themeSwitchAction(_ sender: UISwitch) {

        if sender.isOn == true {
            Theme.shared.isDarkMode = true
            lblStatus.text = "Dark Mode"
            lblStatus.textColor = lblStatus.DarkModeColor

        }
        else {
            Theme.shared.isDarkMode = false
            lblStatus.text = "Day Mode"
            lblStatus.textColor = lblStatus.DayModeColor
        }
    }
```

Also created a Holder that will hold the value of properties.

```
extension UILabel {

    struct Holder {
        static var dark: UIColor = UIColor()
        static var light: UIColor = UIColor()
    }

    @IBInspectable var DayModeColor : UIColor {
        set{
            Holder.dark = newValue
        }
        get{
            return Holder.dark
        }
    }


    @IBInspectable var DarkModeColor : UIColor {
        set{
            Holder.light = newValue
        }

        get{
            return Holder.light
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe while changing the theme, your app UI is not updating. So `awakeFromNib()` should not called. So either you have to manually change the color of all the labels and buttons.

Or better is to use [Method Swizzling](https://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/). For new screens which will be going to appear will call `awakeFromNib()`.

Alternate is to subclass the UILabel and UIButton class for custom themes.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to following,

```
class Theme {
    static let shared = Theme()
    var isDarkMode = Bool()
}

extension UILabel {
    open override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        if Theme.shared.isDarkMode == true {
            // set the DarkMode Color
            self.textColor = UIColor.red
        }
        else {
            // set the DayModeColor
            self.textColor = UIColor.blue
        }
    }
}
```

Remove `@IBInspectable var DayModeColor : UIColor{}` and

`@IBInspectable var DarkModeColor : UIColor{}`

Comment: It may work..but I won't be able to select colours from inspector since i need different colours for many kinds of labels buttons and views and a lot of things

Comment: Please think at the perspective i have explained u

Comment: In your code, if your `switch` is `turn on`, all the label colors become red in your whole project. I tried this. It is working for me.

Comment: i need to select different colours from attribute inspector

Comment: i may need different colours for title..desc...contents and all,,,i don't want to waste time with everything in code